# Update user information using react js and node js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to update the username and the email... the backend is working but the frontend is not updating,

I updated the username and the mail, when I test my update in the frontend, it's the same nothing happend even though i got the alert "admin updated", however when i test the backend there is no issue and it's working .

the backend:

```js
  app.put("/admin/:id", (req, res) => {
    LoginAdmin.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},{
      $set:{
        email : req.body.email,
        adminname: req.body.adminname
      }
    }, function (err, data) {
      if (err){
        res.status(500).send(err)
    } else {
      res.status(200).send({message: 'UPDATED', data: data})
    }
    })
  })
```

the frontend:

```js
const UpdateAdminAccount = (props) => {
    let navigate= useNavigate()
    const initialInputValues = {
      adminname: '',
      email: '',
    } 
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialInputValues)

    //show admin info before updating
    const {id} = useParams()
    useEffect(()=>{
     if(id){
         getSingleAdmin(id)
     }
    },[id])
    const getSingleAdmin = async (id) =>{
        const response = await axios.get(`/admin/${id}`);
        console.log("response", response)
        if (response.status === 200){
            setValues(response.data);
        }
    };

      const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value
        setValues({
          ...values,
          [name]: value,
        })
      }   
 
      const updateAdmin = async (e, id) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
          await axios.put(`/admin/${id}`, {
          ...values
          }
          ).then((res) =>{    
            console.log(res)
              if (res.data.message === 'UPDATED') {
                  alert("admin updated")
                  }
            })   
    };
    return (
            <form method='Post'>
             <ul>
              <li>
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input name="adminname" value={values.adminname} onChange={handleInputChange} type="text" />
              </li>
              <li> 
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input name="email" value={values.email} onChange={handleInputChange} type="email"  />
             </li>
              <li>
              <li>
                   
                  <button className='submit-button' onClick={updateAdmin} type="submit" > 
                    Update
                  </button> :
                  
              </li>
             </ul>
            </form>
            </div>
  
        </div>  
      </div>
    );
}

export default UpdateAdminAccount;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not updating your frontend's state. You should get the values that the backend sent you and use them to update your frontend. Like this:

```js
const UpdateAdminAccount = (props) => {
    let navigate= useNavigate()
    const initialInputValues = {
      adminname: '',
      email: '',
    } 
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialInputValues)

    //show admin info before updating
    const {id} = useParams()
    useEffect(()=>{
     if(id){
         getSingleAdmin(id)
     }
    },[id])
    const getSingleAdmin = async (id) =>{
        const response = await axios.get(`/admin/${id}`);
        console.log("response", response)
        if (response.status === 200){
            setValues(response.data);
        }
    };

      const handleInputChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name
        const value = e.target.value
        setValues({
          ...values,
          [name]: value,
        })
      }   
 
      const updateAdmin = async (e, id) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
          await axios.put(`/admin/${id}`, {
          ...values
          }
          ).then((res) =>{    
            console.log(res)
              if (res.data.message === 'UPDATED') {
                  //Update here
                  setValues(res.data.data)
                  alert("admin updated")
                  }
            })   
    };
    return (
            <form method='Post'>
             <ul>
              <li>
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input name="adminname" value={values.adminname} onChange={handleInputChange} type="text" />
              </li>
              <li> 
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input name="email" value={values.email} onChange={handleInputChange} type="email"  />
             </li>
              <li>
              <li>
                   
                  <button className='submit-button' onClick={updateAdmin} type="submit" > 
                    Update
                  </button> :
                  
              </li>
             </ul>
            </form>
            </div>
  
        </div>  
      </div>
    );
}

export default UpdateAdminAccount;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunatley it's the same problem.